# How can this relation be anti-symmetric and symmetric at the same time?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, symmetry

Why is this anti-symmetrical and symmetrical at the same time? I get how it is anti-symmetric because There is no pair such as (1,2) & (2,1) but how did it become symmetrical?

```
R is a relation on the set of integers
R = {(a,b) | a = b}
```

Comment: If $R$ is some relation that is both antisymmetric and symmetric, what can you conclude about $R$?

Comment: But how can it be symmetric when there is no pair where (a,b) & (b,a) are in the Relation where a is not equal to b?

Comment: What is your definition of symmetric?

Comment: It's symmetric because whenever $(a,b)\in R$, then $(b,a)$ must be in $R$ also.  In fact, any other relation on the integers that is both symmetric and anti-symmetric must be a subset of this one.

Comment: @wj32 a relation is symmetric if (a,b) & (b,a) are in the relation where a is not equal to b, a relation is antisymmetric if there are no distinct a and b with (a,b) & (b,a) in the relation

Comment: @DavidWallace but then it would imply that (a = b)

Comment: You may wish to check your definition of symmetric.  You may have misunderstood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(a,b)$ is in $R$ then $a=b$ [by the definition given for $R$] so $(b,a)=(a,b)$ so $(b,a)$ is in $R$.